# Java 8 map Integer stream to <T> stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am a complete noob in Java 8 features and I am trying to generate a stream of Double objects as a result of processing a stream of Integers, something like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(integer -> 50.0);
```

So I end up with a stream that looks like:

```
{50.0, 50.0, ... 50.0}
```

Now, I know `forEach` doesn't work like that and that this specific case can be solved in other simpler ways, but it's just for the sake of exposition.

Basically, what I am looking for is similar to a `forEach` except that it expects a return value for each element and is able to produce a stream too.

Comment: Is'nt [mapToDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.IntToDoubleFunction-) or [mapToObj](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, the type of operation you're talking about is a [map operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)): you want to apply a function to each element of a list and return a new list of those results. Here is an example which converts a stream of integers into a custom class and then collects them into a `List`:

```java
IntStream.range(1, 10)
    .mapToObj(n -> new MyClass(n))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Alternatively - using a method reference 
IntStream.range(1, 10)
    .mapToObj(MyClass::new)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Alternatively - convert from a stream of primitive ints to a stream 
// of Integer objects (i.e. boxed ints) first so we can use methods not
// available on the IntStream object
IntStream.range(1, 10).boxed()
    .map(MyClass::new)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As has been mentioned in another answer, you can also use the `mapToDouble` method for the specific case you mentioned.

Comment: What is the difference between using `.map` with and without `.boxed` first?

Comment: @arielnmz - if you read the javadoc you'll see that `IntStream` is an "int primitive specialization of Stream", so a lot of its methods are for "primitive int" operations, hence the `map` method has a different signature (i.e. different argument and return types) to the `map` method available in the more generic `Stream` class. The "boxed" method returns a normal `Stream` of "boxed" ints (a.k.a. Integer objects), i.e. it converts your stream of primitive ints to Integer objects and you get to use a `Stream` object instead, which is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You may use map helper function on your integer stream to do to. Check out this code below.

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class MapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToDouble(number -> 50.0).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

Comment: The expected Double stream in the example was just for exposition, I actually need to get a stream of an arbitrary class; and though I may be misunderstanding the purpose of the `mapToX` methods (mapToDouble, specifically, which I assume just sequentially converts the Integers to Doubles), mapToObj in my case does the trick by letting me *return* a stream of Objs that I can then cast into the class Im really expecting.

Comment: The solution actually is something like `IntStream.range(0,row.length).mapToObj(i -> new MyClass(i));` which I can follow with something like `toArray(MyClass[]::new)`;

Comment: I suggest you just using `.map` helper in that case like this, `.map(number -> new MyClass(number))`. I suggest you not to do casting since it is awkward a bit.

Comment: I think I can't use it that way since using `map()` on an `IntStream` still expects an `Integer` as return type.

Comment: Yes you are correct, in Java8 streams you can't. But you can use RxJava for this. I'll update my answer with RxJava approach.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. Let me remove unwanted parts, since it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream.generate` instead of `Stream.range`. This is more appropriate for your case, because you don't use values from range:

```
List<Double> collect = Stream.generate(() -> Double.valueOf(50.0))
                             .limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Well, for *this specific case*, the best solution would be `List<Double> list = Collections.nCopies(10, 50.0);`. For other cases, `IntStream.range(…).mapToObj(…)` is known to be more efficient than `Stream.generate(…).limit(…)` with the current implementation. Besides that, they’re just equivalent.